# Formal syntax for function/variable definition

Tags: language-agnostic, syntax

I remember somewhere seeing such a notation for formally defining a variable:

```
variable_name: type
```

And similarly:

```
function_name(....): return_type
```

But I don't remember and I can't find the formal definition of this syntax.

My question first is, is this really a formal syntax or did somebody just make it up? My second question, can you give me the name for it, or a reference?

I am asking because I was wondering how the function arguments are defined. Would it be like this?

```
function(arg1:type1, arg2:type2): type
```

If so, how are default values shown?

Comment: Dude, dry but the question is a contradiction in itself. Having a formal syntax equalsis equivallent to having a language. Unless you have parameters in the  meta language level. This is a very complicated topic. Easier if you try meta- programming system from jetbrains. This is not an ad btw I'm using it too and I'm not affiliated with them. Sorry for errors typing on a smartphone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax you describe is used in the [ML family](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ML_%28programming_language%29) of programming languages. In [Standard ML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_ML), which has a formal semantics, there are no default values, everything must be initialized when declared.

Comment: It is more a Pascal- (or Modula-) like syntax than ML (functions are obviously not curried).

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but I don't see such a notation in either of the links :-?

Comment: @Shahbaz, Look for "type annotations." Since ML has type inference, you don't see explicit types used much, but the syntax, when you do, is as you describe. One xample on the SML page is: fun bftQ (q : 'a tree queue) : 'a list

Comment: @SK-Logic, ML functions often take tuple arguments; here's an example from PolyML: fun prettyPrintWithMarkup(stream : string -> unit, lineWidth : int): PolyML.pretty -> unit (* from http://polyml.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/polyml/trunk/polyml/basis/FinalPolyML.530.sml?view=markup&pathrev=722 *)